# Memory semantics of java.lang.ref.Reference methods

Tags: java, concurrency, reference, volatile, consistency

I am developing some concurrent algorithms which deal with Reference objects. I am using java 17.

The thing is I don't know what's the memory semantics of operations like get, clear or refersTo. It isn't documented in the Javadoc.

Looking into the source code of OpenJdk, the referent has no modifier, such as volatile (while the next pointer for reference queues is volatile).
Also, get implementation is trivial, but it is an intrinsic candidate. clear and refersTo are native. So I don't know what they really do.

When the GC clears a reference, I have to assume that all threads will see it cleared, or otherwise they would see a reference to an object (in process of being) garbage collected, but it's just an informal guess.

Is there any warranty about the memory semantics of all these operations?

If there isn't, is there a way to obtain the same warranries of a volatile access by invoking, for instance, a fence operation before and/or after calling one of these operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `clear()` on a reference object, it will only clear this particular `Reference` object without any impact on the rest of your application and no special memory semantics. It’s exactly like you have seen in the code, an assignment of `null` to a field which has no `volatile` modifier.

Mind [the documentation of `clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#clear()):

> This method is invoked only by Java code; when the garbage collector clears references it does so directly, without invoking this method.

So this is not related to the event of the GC clearing a reference. Your assumption “that all threads will see it cleared” when the GC clears a reference is correct. The [documentation of `WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) states:

> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that an object is [weakly reachable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability). At that time it will atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references.

So at this point, not only all threads will agree that a weak reference has been cleared, they will also agree that all weak references to the same object have been cleared. A similar statement can be found at `SoftReference` and `PhantomReference`.

[The Java Language Specification, §12.6.2. Interaction with the Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.2) refers to points where such an atomic clear may happen as *reachability decision points*. It specifies interactions between these points and other program actions, in terms of “*comes-before di*” and “*comes-after di*” relationships, the most import ones being:

> If *r* is a read that sees a write *w* and *r* comes-before *di*, then *w* must come-before *di*.
>
> If *x* and *y* are synchronization actions on the same variable or monitor such that *so(x, y)* ([§17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)) and *y* comes-before *di*, then *x* must come-before *di*.

So, the GC action will be inserted into the synchronization order and even a racy read could not subvert it, but it’s important to keep in mind that the exact location of the reachability decision point is not known to the application. It’s obviously somewhere between the last point where `get()` returned a non-`null` reference or `refersTo(null)` returned `false` and the first point where `get()` returned `null` or `refersTo(null)` returned `true`.

For practical applications, the fact that once the reference reports the object to be garbage collected you can be sure that it won’t reappear anywhere¹, is enough. Just keep the reference object private, to be sure that not someone invoked `clear()` on it.

¹ Letting things like “finalizer resurrection aside”

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you. Just to make sure I got everything right, all of the get, refersTo and clear methods access the referent in plain mode, right? In my case, many thread will access the same reference, and I need to either make sure the clear performed by one thread is seen by all other threads (as if it was a volatile set to null) or try to rethink my program in a way that this doesn't matter (or maybe to force all accesses to the reference to follow the same pointer and CAS it to itself after the clear - if the JIT compiler doesn't optimize such code away). Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to rethink your program. Reading the reference to the `WeakReference` and reading the contained reference are two distinct actions, so you can’t change the first action in a way that would make these two actions atomic. It’s always possible that someone calls `clear()` in-between these two calls which may or may not be seen. But even if a thread writes a new value to a `volatile` variable while *n* threads are reading the variable at (roughly) the same time, we can’t predict, how many threads read the old and how many read the new value. There’s too much linear thinking in your idea.

Comment: Well, there is too little space in the comments to write the whole idea and why in this case a volatile clear would fill my needs. But anyway I will have to live without it and I am shaping up a solution that will work anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe it’s worth opening a new question regarding the actual use case…